# Replace sequential product and sum with a faster matrix operation in 3D

Tags: numpy, theano, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

In my current theano script the bottleneck is the following code:

```
import numpy as np

axis = 0
prob = np.random.random( ( 1, 1000, 50 ) )
cases = np.random.random( ( 1000, 1000, 50 ) )

start = time.time(  )
for i in xrange( 1000 ):
    result = ( cases * prob ).sum( axis=1-axis, keepdims=True )
print '3D naive method took {} seconds'.format( time.time() - start )
print result.shape
print
```

I had seen in 2D case that replacing elementwise+sum with a dot product gave me 5x speedup. Are there any matrix operations that could help me out in this case?

**EDIT**:

*Divakar* gave me a version based on *einsum*. However, my intention was to port it to *theano* and *einsum* is not supported on *theano*. So alternatives portable to *theano* are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
result = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ik', prob, cases)[:,None,:]
```

Another one with [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) -

```
result = np.matmul(prob.transpose(2,0,1), cases.T).T
```

Runtime test -

```
In [70]: axis = 0
    ...: prob = np.random.random( ( 1, 1000, 50 ) )
    ...: cases = np.random.random( ( 1000, 1000, 50 ) )
    ...: 

In [71]: out1 = ( cases * prob ).sum( axis=1-axis, keepdims=True )

In [72]: out2 = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ik', prob, cases)[:,None,:]

In [73]: out3 = np.matmul(prob.transpose(2,0,1), cases.T).T

In [74]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[74]: True

In [75]: np.allclose(out1, out3)
Out[75]: True

In [76]: %timeit ( cases * prob ).sum( axis=1-axis, keepdims=True )
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop

In [77]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ik', prob, cases)[:,None,:]
10 loops, best of 3: 44.1 ms per loop

In [78]: %timeit np.matmul(prob.transpose(2,0,1), cases.T).T
10 loops, best of 3: 44 ms per loop
```

Comment: Divakar, thank you for you reply. I was not aware of _einsum_ and on my PC the speedup is even higher. However, I was planning on porting this operation to _theano_, but it seems _einsum_ is one of the few matrix operations not implemented. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @Sharapolas [`numpy.matmul in Theano`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169776/numpy-matmul-in-theano) with the second approach?

Comment: the solution in the PR seems to be CPU only?

Comment: @Sharapolas Not sure really, not an expert on theano.

Comment: I will give a shot to that PR and in case all works well I will accept the answer. Otherwise, are you aware of any other functions that could do that? Both _matmul_ and _einsum_ were new to me, so wondering whether there are more. Also, I somehow think it should be possible to do with just _reshape_, _transpose_ and _dot_

Comment: @Sharapolas The requirement of keeping the last axis aligned restricts our options. If that weren't there, we could have explored `np.dot`  or `np.tensordot` too.

Comment: but we could reshape and merge the first and last axis, no?

Comment: @Sharapolas As I said we need to keep the last axis aligned between the two input arrays and kept in the output. `np.dot` or `np.tensordot` doesn't allow that as the axes that are not sum-reduced would be considered as two separate axes and won't be aligned.

Comment: the PR is _theano_ capable, but not GPU so it is not yet what I needed.